# How can the value change immediately after I clicked add or minus

Tags: vue.js

Hi currently I am making a add & minus function and the problem I am facing is once I clicked add or minus, the value still remain the same... I use the watch property also and it still not working

The get_list is calling from a API

```
<b-row v-for="(data,i) in get_list" :key="i" class="mt-3 mx-0">>
 <b-button pill
     class="quantity-btn btn-secondary"
     @click="addQuantity(data.id_product,data.id_style)"
  >
       <span style="transform: translateY(-5%);">+</span>
  </b-button>

  <div class="px-2">
     <b-form-input type="number" min="1" :max="data.quantity_available" :value="quantity"  v-model="data.cart_quantity" class="quantity-input"></b-form-input>
  </div>
   <b-button pill
      class="quantity-btn btn-secondary"
      @click="minusQuantity(data.id_product,data.id_style)"
    >
     <span style="transform: translateY(-5%);">-</span>
    </b-button>
</b-row>
```

script

```
 data: () => ({
 
        get_list: [],
        quantity:0,

       
    }),

method :{

        addQuantity(id,style) {
            this.quantity++
            this.updateQuantity(id,style)
        },
        minusQuantity(id,style) {
            
                this.quantity--
                this.updateQuantity(id,style)
            
        },
},

 watch: {
        quantity(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('new'+newVal)
      
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.op`? Where did you define the `op`?

Comment: @NehaSoni done edited , can just ignore that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this code in code proved above.

```
<div class="px-2">
     <b-form-input type="number" min="1" :max="data.quantity_available" :value="quantity"  v-model="data.cart_quantity" class="quantity-input"></b-form-input>
  </div>
```

Here it seems **cart_quantity** is getting used in template instead of **quantity** due to this it's not getting updated.

to fix this issue, you can update the **cart_quantity** property of the data object instead of the **quantity** data property in the **addQuantity** and **minusQuantity**

```
methods: {
  addQuantity(id, style) {
    this.get_list.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id_product === id && item.id_style === style) {
        item.cart_quantity++;
      }
    });
  },
  minusQuantity(id, style) {
    this.get_list.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id_product === id && item.id_style === style) {
        item.cart_quantity--;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Please remove **watch** property as well it seems not required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are performing the **add/minus** operation on the `quantity` variable but in the template, you are using the `cart_quantity` variable which is not increasing/decreasing.

So, either use `quantity` or `cart_quantity` as per your logic.

```
addQuantity(id, style) {
  this.cart_quantity++;
  // If you are using quantity as v-model
  // this.quantity++
  this.updateQuantity(id, style);
},
minusQuantity(id, style) {
  this.cart_quantity--;
  // If you are using quantity as v-model
  // this.quantity--
  this.updateQuantity(id, style);
},
```

One more thing, you don't need to use `value` and `v-model` together at the same time. If you want to give some initial value to the `input`, simply assign that value to your `cart_quantity` on mounted and use it further.

The last thing, you don't need a watcher as well.